# Computing cosine similarity between specific strings using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble, cosine-similarity

Let's say I have two datasets like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(
abel = rnorm(10),
abby= rnorm(10),
bret= rnorm(10))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
      abel    abby    bret
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 -1.24   -0.498   0.663 
 2 -0.179  -1.49    0.619 
 3  1.36   -2.19    1.43  
 4  0.145   0.520   1.01  
 5 -0.873   1.21    0.0441
 6 -0.0434  0.103   0.201 
 7 -0.472  -0.389  -1.86  
 8 -0.486  -0.318   0.291 
 9  0.0884 -0.0458 -0.527 
10 -0.0734  0.0780  0.709 

df2<- tibble(
barista = rnorm(10),
beekeeper=rnorm(10),
economist = rnorm(10),
lawyer = rnorm(10),
ranger = rnorm(10),
trader = rnorm(10))

# A tibble: 10 × 6
   barista beekeeper economist lawyer ranger  trader
     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  -0.577   -0.179      1.60   0.923  0.613 -0.446 
 2  -1.22     0.118      1.04   0.217  0.115  0.184 
 3   0.881    0.0564     0.222 -0.622 -0.543 -1.38  
 4   0.731   -1.60       0.701  1.15  -0.189 -0.0284
 5   0.435    0.129     -1.76  -0.127  0.743 -0.932 
 6   1.57    -0.812      1.24   1.05   0.147  1.34  
 7   1.66     0.624      1.34   1.01   2.27  -0.223 
 8   0.116    0.334      0.553  0.794 -1.54   0.0656
 9   0.672    1.11       0.752  0.187  0.594  0.468 
10  -1.35     0.259     -1.63  -0.738 -1.96  -0.773
```

I want to compute cosine similarity between the two datasets in this manner:
select the first word 'abel' in df1, ignore the first letter, take the second letter "b", look for words starting with "b" in df2 and compute cosine similarity. Repeat the process with the remaining letters in the first word.

Do the same with all the words of df1.

Has to account for repetitions in alphabets of df1. For instance, the word 'abby', has 'b" twice, it should be counted only once. Also, there is no word in df2 with 'y' so NA should be returned.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you computing cosine similarity between? The word in df1 and the matches in df2? Or within the df2 matches?

Comment: @dcsuka for example, for the first word 'abel', we would compute cosine similarity between (abel, barista), (abel, economist), (abel, lawyer). Essentially, we are taking the word 'abel' ignore first letter 'a', pick second letter 'b', lookup word starting with 'b' in df2 (that is barista) and then compute cosine similarity between abel and barista. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution gathers all combinations then calculates similarity. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)

df1 <- tibble(
abel = rnorm(10),
abby= rnorm(10),
bret= rnorm(10))

df2<- tibble(
barista = rnorm(10),
beekeeper=rnorm(10),
economist = rnorm(10),
lawyer = rnorm(10),
ranger = rnorm(10),
trader = rnorm(10))


df_2 <- colnames(df2)
df_1 <- as_tibble_col(colnames(df1), "col1") %>%
  mutate(col2 = map(col1, function(x) mutate(as_tibble_col(unique(unlist(str_split(x, ""))[-1]), "first_letters"),
                                             match = map(first_letters, ~df_2[which(str_detect(df_2, paste0("^", .)))])))) %>%
  unnest(everything()) %>%
  unnest(everything()) %>%
  mutate(cos_sim = stringsim(col1, match, "cosine"))

# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   col1  first_letters match     cos_sim
#   <chr> <chr>         <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 abel  b             barista     0.5  
# 2 abel  b             beekeeper   0.557
# 3 abel  e             economist   0.151
# 4 abel  l             lawyer      0.612
# 5 abby  b             barista     0.544
# 6 abby  b             beekeeper   0.152
# 7 bret  r             ranger      0.530
# 8 bret  e             economist   0.302
# 9 bret  t             trader      0.707
```

Comment: That seems perfect. Could you please explain the code a bit? Thanks so much

Comment: Sure, it might help to run each step individually to see the result. The meat is in the step that starts with `df_1 <-`. The `col2 = map` part creates a nested tibble based on the elements of col1 taken one at a time. Splitting on an empty string divides into letters, the `[-1]` index removes the first character, and `unique` removes duplicates like b in abby. That vector is taken as the nested tibble, and the first `[1]`match in `df_2` which starts with that letter is taken before unnesting and calculating cosine similarity.

Comment: additional question.  So, shouldn't the output compute cosine similarity between 'abel' and 'beekeeper' too? Also, what if I also want to compute cosine similarities between the unmatched values between df1 and df2? For instance, between 'abel' and 'ranger', 'abel' and 'trader' etc. Thanks again

Comment: Your original comment instructions skipped abel and beekeeper, so I assumed you did not want second matches as such. I update to allow for them. To get the rest of the matches, just get every possible combination of the words and use the stringsim function.

Comment: I am a little confused about stringsim. I tried to compute cosine similarity using lsa::cosine and the results seem to be different

Comment: I am not an expert about string similarity scores. I just found a function to implement  some kind of cosine similarity to your problem. If you read up on it and find one you like more, it is possible to swap it out while retaining this scaffold.